# How do I perform a conditional action based on a response in Gatling?

Tags: java, scala, performance, load-testing, gatling

I have a scenario which load tests a sample API . Now I want to store those failed accounts of the scenario and and put them back in the feeder. I have a global hash table where I want to store the failed accounts.

I am not able to figure out how to do this action using doif , check or any other Gatling DSL.

```
ScenarioBuilder scenarioBuilder = scenario("getImage Request")
        .repeat(8)
        .on(
        feed(feeder)
        .exec(session -> {
            
            
            String token = dataapi.createStrongToken("abc", "doj");
            Session session1 = session.set("token", token);
            return session1;
        })
        .feed(csv("clientType.csv").random())
        .exec(http("uploadImage").get("/image")
                .check(status().gte(200), status().lte(304))
                .header("token",session -> session.getString("token"))
                .queryParam("accountId", "#{accountId}")
                
        );
```

You can imagine a custom feeder or a csv as plausable.  If I get a response in range of 4xx or 5xx I want to store a the failed account in a global hash table/linked list. Can someone please guide me how to implement this case ? Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `status().saveAs("status")` check so you can build your `doIf` condition:

```java
.doIf(session -> {
  int status = session.getInt("status");
  return status < 200 || status > 304;
}).then(
  exec(
    session -> {
      String accountId = session.getString("accountId");
      // perform accountId storage
      return session;
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: what you suggested does work Thanks. But I am facing another issue now. For large number of users say 1000. I am able to get the session variable "status" for initial some requests but then I start getting element not Found exception for "status". Its like 100 Virtual users and each user doing 10 sequential requests(repeat) . 100x10=1000.

Comment: Right, that's a known bug that will be fixed in 3.8.0, see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4229. When the first request crashed (eg connection timeout, request timeout, etc), you don't have a stored "status". In the meaning, please write `String accountId = session.get("accountId");` (casting form).